# Is it possible to update free apps from another account?

Tags: mac-appstore, software-update

By what I've already read, I know that if you have *purchased* an app in the Mac App Store with the account **X**, then you can update it only by logging into **X**. Now the question that arises is: What if the downloaded app is *free*, does the same rule apply or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the same principle applies. For Apple, it is a purchased product, though in one case the price was $0.
So it's not transferable from account to account. As a developer, I know one normal case that is: the app is free for one day. Then the app turns paid. If a user could transfer to another account, then it would be a problem for the dev since it may be transferred to anyone.